# Xcode (Swift): Changing UIButton attributes in a different UIViewController class than that in which they were referenced

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

Quick note before my actual question: I am very new (a few days in) to XCode and Swift. I have programming experience in scientific platforms such as matlab, mathematica, and IGOR.

My question:
In my main view controller I have an IBOutlet for a UIButton which I have implemented in the main story board.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    ....    

    @IBOutlet weak var chip_a1: UIButton!

    ....
}
```

Also in my main view controller, and within an IBAction method, I'm able to access the hidden attribute as follows:

```
@IBAction func chip_a1_touchupinside(sender: UIButton) {
    self.chip_a1.hidden = true
}
```

But when I try to access this property from within a different view controller class as follows:

```
class endgame: UIViewController {  
    ....  
    @IBAction func playagain_touchupinside(sender: UIButton) {
        var handle = ViewController()
        // make the states of all the chips visible
        handle.chip_a1.hidden = false  // this is the line that gives me an ERROR
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    ....
}
```

The error is this:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Any help with understanding/fixing this issue would be much appreciated. Happy to provide more detail if I need to.

Best,
Alex.

Answer (score 0):

You create UIViewcontroller with xib File

You have to Change

```
var handle = ViewController()
```

to

```
var handle = ViewController(nibName: "ViewControllerNibfileName", bundle: nil)
```

as Button is IBOutlet and need the nibfile loaded with viewcontroller

Comment: Hi again. Thanks for the response Mohamed. Unfortunately I still get the same error. I even tried instantiating ViewController beforehand in order to get the NibfileName:  
        var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var ViewControllerid = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as UIViewController
        var handle = ViewController(nibName: "ViewControllerid", bundle: nil)

Comment: Sometimes newly created ViewControllers Xib are not initiated and Loade until you use the view

      ...> handle.view.alpha = 1